# Place the button div next to table div

Tags: html, css

I have a table created and a button. I am trying to align button div to right of table div with class named as .wrap-table but its not aligning correctly.

I used float:left property to button class but  its aligning below the table not to right of table

Is there any property i am missing out to be added in css ?

Please help.

```css
body{
    overflow: hidden;
}


.wrap-table100 {
  width: 60%;

}
.table100 {
  background-color: #fff;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

th, td {
  font-weight: unset;
  padding-right: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}

.column1 {
  width: 25%;
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.column2 {
  width: 20%;
}

.column3 {
  width: 20%;
}

.column4 {
  width: 20%;
}


.table100-head th {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
}

.table100-body td {
  padding-top: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
}

/*==================================================================
[ Fix header ]*/
.table100 {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.table100-head {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.table100-body {
  max-height: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.table100.ver2 .table100-head {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -o-box-shadow: 0 5px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 5px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.table100.ver2 th {
  font-family: Lato-Bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fa4251;
  line-height: 1.4;

  background-color: transparent;
}

.table100.ver2 td {
  font-family: Lato-Regular;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #808080;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

.table100.ver2 .table100-body tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

/*---------------------------------------------*/

.table100.ver2 {
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 0px 40px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0px 40px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0px 40px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -o-box-shadow: 0 0px 40px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 0px 40px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}


/* scrollbar body */
.js-pscroll {
  position: relative;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
  <div class="wrap-table100">
    <div class="table100 ver2 m-b-110">
      <div class="table100-head">
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr class="row100 head">
              <th class="cell100 column1">Name</th>
              <th class="cell100 column2">Date</th>
              <th class="cell100 column3">Type</th>
              <th class="cell100 column4">Status</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
        </table>
      </div>

      <div class="table100-body js-pscroll" >
        <table>
          <tbody >
                <tr class="row100 body"style="border-bottom:1px solid black" >
                   <tr class="row100 body">
                    <td class="cell100 column1">Kavya</td>
                    <td class="cell100 column2">01-01-2000</td>
                    <td class="cell100 column3">Datamodel</td>
                    <td class="cell100 column4">completed</td>
                </tr>

                 <tr class="row100 body">
                    <td class="cell100 column1">Kavya</td>
                    <td class="cell100 column2">01-01-2000</td>
                    <td class="cell100 column3">Datamodel</td>
                    <td class="cell100 column4">completed</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
  </div>
  </div>
   <div class="dropdown">
                    <button type="button" class="dropbtn">dropdown menu</button>
                    
         
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your problem lies under your HTML structure and you must move your button div under the main container instead of div with class `wrap-table100` so since you are using flexbox already there is no need to use float and the row flex container will do the job for you.

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container-table100 {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #f4f5f7;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 33px 30px;
}

.wrap-table100 {
  width: 60%;
}

.table100 {
  background-color: #fff;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

th,
td {
  font-weight: unset;
  padding-right: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}

.column1 {
  width: 25%;
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.column2 {
  width: 20%;
}

.column3 {
  width: 20%;
}

.column4 {
  width: 20%;
}

.table100-head th {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
}

.table100-body td {
  padding-top: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
}


/*==================================================================
[ Fix header ]*/

.table100 {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.table100-head {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.table100-body {
  max-height: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.table100.ver2 .table100-head {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -o-box-shadow: 0 5px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 5px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.table100.ver2 th {
  font-family: Lato-Bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fa4251;
  line-height: 1.4;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.table100.ver2 td {
  font-family: Lato-Regular;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #808080;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

.table100.ver2 .table100-body tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}


/*---------------------------------------------*/

.table100.ver2 {
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 0px 40px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0px 40px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0px 40px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -o-box-shadow: 0 0px 40px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 0px 40px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}


/* scrollbar body */

.js-pscroll {
  position: relative;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-table100">
  <div class="wrap-table100">
    <div class="table100 ver2 m-b-110">
      <div class="table100-head">
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr class="row100 head">
              <th class="cell100 column1">Name</th>
              <th class="cell100 column2">Date</th>
              <th class="cell100 column3">Type</th>
              <th class="cell100 column4">Status</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
        </table>
      </div>

      <div class="table100-body js-pscroll">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr class="row100 body" style="border-bottom:1px solid black">
              <tr class="row100 body">
                <td class="cell100 column1">Kavya</td>
                <td class="cell100 column2">01-01-2000</td>
                <td class="cell100 column3">Datamodel</td>
                <td class="cell100 column4">completed</td>
              </tr>

              <tr class="row100 body">
                <td class="cell100 column1">Kavya</td>
                <td class="cell100 column2">01-01-2000</td>
                <td class="cell100 column3">Datamodel</td>
                <td class="cell100 column4">completed</td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button type="button" class="dropbtn">dropdown menu</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I editted my question because the main container is causing a lot of problem in alignment .can you please check the updated code and help me out.

Comment: @kavya I'm not really sure, what is your problem here, so you need to clarify it. And changing the question after you accept an answer and it fits your problem, is not a common thing in SO, so it's better to avoid it. But if in any case, you can't use `container` div or whatever you can define another simple wrapping div instead of it and make it flex. If you don't want to do it at all, one of the possible approaches to solve your situation is to add `float: left;` to `.wrap-table100`.

Answer (score 0):

There were some closing tags missing. I edited that.

```css
body{
    overflow: hidden;
}
.container-table100 {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #f4f5f7;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 33px 30px;
}

.wrap-table100 {
  width: 60%;

}
.table100 {
  background-color: #fff;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

th, td {
  font-weight: unset;
  padding-right: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}

.column1 {
  width: 25%;
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.column2 {
  width: 20%;
}

.column3 {
  width: 20%;
}

.column4 {
  width: 20%;
}


.table100-head th {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
}

.table100-body td {
  padding-top: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
}

/*==================================================================
[ Fix header ]*/
.table100 {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.table100-head {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.table100-body {
  max-height: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.table100.ver2 .table100-head {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -o-box-shadow: 0 5px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 5px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.table100.ver2 th {
  font-family: Lato-Bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fa4251;
  line-height: 1.4;

  background-color: transparent;
}

.table100.ver2 td {
  font-family: Lato-Regular;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #808080;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

.table100.ver2 .table100-body tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

/*---------------------------------------------*/

.table100.ver2 {
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 0px 40px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0px 40px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0px 40px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -o-box-shadow: 0 0px 40px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 0px 40px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}


/* scrollbar body */
.js-pscroll {
  position: relative;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.dropdown{
float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-table100">
  <div class="wrap-table100">
    <div class="table100 ver2 m-b-110">
      <div class="table100-head">
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr class="row100 head">
              <th class="cell100 column1">Name</th>
              <th class="cell100 column2">Date</th>
              <th class="cell100 column3">Type</th>
              <th class="cell100 column4">Status</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
        </table>
      </div>

      <div class="table100-body js-pscroll" >
        <table>
          <tbody >
            <tr class="row100 body"style="border-bottom:1px solid black" >
              <tr class="row100 body">
                <td class="cell100 column1">Kavya</td>
                <td class="cell100 column2">01-01-2000</td>
                <td class="cell100 column3">Datamodel</td>
                <td class="cell100 column4">completed</td>
              </tr>

              <tr class="row100 body">
                <td class="cell100 column1">Kavya</td>
                <td class="cell100 column2">01-01-2000</td>
                <td class="cell100 column3">Datamodel</td>
                <td class="cell100 column4">completed</td>
              </tr>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button type="button" class="dropbtn">dropdown menu</button>
  </div>
</div>
```